# Cakephp 2 issue with getting data in multiple secltion

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, multiple-tables

I have stored the data in multiple select option in two tables.

**Table:**
Users:

```
id      user_name  status
1       test      1  
2       test2     1  
3       test3     1  
4       test4     1
```

hobbies:

```
id      hobby_name
1      Cricket        
2      Movie        
3      Football
4      Music
5      Dance
```

I have saved the data like below:

```
id      user_id  hobby_id
1       1        5  
2       1        19  
3       2        17  
4       2        18
```

Each user has multiple hobbies. Now, when I edit the `user_id` 1 I want to show the selected id's in multiple select box.

I have fetched the `hobbies` data in `UsersCroller.php` like below:

```
$this->loadModel('Hobby');
$hobbies = $this->Hobby->find('list', array('fields' => array('Hobby.id', 'Hobby.hobbyname'), 'recursive' => -1));
$this->set(compact('hobbies'));
```

Created the select box dropdown in `admin_add.ctp` like below:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('hobbies', array("label" => false, 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $hobbies, "empty"=>"Select Hobbies", "div" => false, "class" => "m-wrap span12 validate[required]", "data-errormessage-value-missing" => "Please select the hobbies!" )); ?>
```

How I can get these records when I edit and show the multiple selection.

Comment: can you show checkboxes here?

Comment: have you try 'multiple' => true

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the `'multiple' => true`.

Comment: How are `user_id`s edited? Im justr trying to work out in my head what the relationship is between editting the user id and displaying selected ids

Comment: are you passing array in 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected like this

Comment: Is you question about editing data? querying data, or displaying the data?

Comment: @JasonJoslin, yes I want to edit the data if user want to remove or add one more hobby.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$results = $this->Users->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'user_hobbies',
            'alias' => 'UserHobies',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserHobies.id = User.id'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'UserHobies.id' => 4   //  where user_id=4
    ),
    'fields' => array('Users.*,UserHobies.*'),
    ));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try the above answer and will get beck to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below form input and pass selected id's and all hobbies.

```
    $selected = array(5, 19);
    $options = array(5, 19, 17, 18);

    echo $this->Form->input('Hobbies', array('multiple' => true, 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected));
```

Comment: How, I can get the selected values from database in the `admin_edit.ctp`.

Comment: you can fetch values using user_id and you will got  like below and create array with hobby_id in $selected array
id   user_id  hobby_id
1       1        5  
2       1        19

Comment: Ahmeds answer is the correct one. $options should be the result of a query of all hobbies and `$selected` should be a list of hobbies that belong to the user.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP will do all that stuff for you if you set up everything properly.

**Controller**

```
$user = $this->User->findById($id);
$this->request->data = $user;

// assigning the $user from the database with the associated HABTM
// to $this->request->data will auto-populate the input

$hobbies = $this->Hobby->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Hobby.id', 'Hobby.hobbyname')
));
$this->set(compact('hobbies'));
```

**View**

```
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend' => 'Hobbies',
    'Hobby.Hobby' => array(
        'label' => false,
            'type' => 'select',
            'multiple' => 'checkbox' // optional – I like checkboxes more
        )
    )
);
```

**Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Hobby');
```